# How to get params in nested routes on react router dom v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

This is how I have defined my router.

```
   <Switch>
     {routes.map((route, index) => (
        <Route
          {...this.props}
          path={`/${route}`}
          key={index}
          component={props => (
            <Layout
              {...props}
            />
          )}
        />
      ))}
      <Route component={() => <p>Not Found</p>} />
    <Switch>
```

I generate a few routes from the `routes` array and for any `route` that does not match it goes to the not found.

Inside the `Layout` component I have further created further routes like this -

```
   <div className={"Actionbar"}>          
      <Route
        path={`${props.match.url}/:item`}
        component={() => <EditCategory {...props} />}
      />            
    </div>
```

When I navigate to a nested route, lets say `/edibles/icecream`, i should be able to see `icecream` as a param value for property `item`, right? I don't see it and i can't seem to figure out how to get the `id` param value in this nested routing use case. My `param` object looks empty now.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution. `props` needs to be passed along with the `route`. Like this -

```
<div className={"Actionbar"}>          
  <Route
    path={`${props.match.url}/:item`}
    render={(props) => <EditCategory {...props} />}
  />            
</div>
```

Missing this doesn't pass the `match` values